# Автоматический перезапуск сервера при обрыве связи с клиентом

Tags: java

Добрый день, при передаче более одного файла возникает такая ситуация что клиент в процессе передаче данных может отпасть и тогда на сервере выскакивает такая ошибка:

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readLong(Unknown Source)
at server.connect(Server_v0.java:104)
at server.<init>(Server_v0.java:78)
at server.main(Server_v0.java:62)
```

И пока сервер не перезагрузить в ручную связь с клиентом не восстанавливается как можно это исправить ? Добавил метод new Server_v0();
в catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace(); Заработало но как то очень не корректно сначала выдаёт кучу ошибок затем останавливается и может принимать файлы после обрыва. Может есть более нормальное решение ?

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

И так три раза

Сервер

```
public static void main(String[] arg) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

           new Server_v0();

       }

        Server_v0(){

            JFrame f = new JFrame("Server");
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setSize(200, 250);
            f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            area = new JTextArea();
            f.add(area);

            f.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            f.setVisible(true);
            connect();

        }

     public void connect(){

         int port = 60000;
         int connection = 1000;

         try {
         @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port, connection);
         area.append("Wait connect...");

         while(true){
             Socket socket = ss.accept();

             InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
             DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(in);

             int filesCount = din.readInt();//получаем количество файлов
             area.setText("Передается " + filesCount + " файлов\n");

             for(int i = 0; i<filesCount; i++){
                 area.append("Принят " + (i+1) + " файл: \n");

                 long fileSize = din.readLong(); // получаем размер файла

                 fileName = din.readUTF(); //приём имени файла



            area.append("Имя файла: " + fileName+"\n");
            area.append("Размер файла: " + fileSize + " байт\n");

              byte[] buffer = new byte[64*1024];
              FileOutputStream outF = new FileOutputStream("D://Photo_and_Video//" + fileName);

              int count, total = 0;

              while ((count = din.read(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(buffer.length, fileSize-total))) != -1){               
                  total += count;
                  outF.write(buffer, 0, count);

                  if(total == fileSize){
                      break;
                  }

              }

              outF.flush();
              outF.close();

              area.append("Файл принят\n---------------------------------\n");            


             }
         }
     }
     catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
          new Server_v0();
     }
    }
```

Comment: Клиент должен сам переподключиться.

Comment: @Russtam причём здесь клиент ? ошибку ловит сервер

Comment: Что значит при чем? Связь разоврало, переподключится и повторить попытку должен клиент. Вы же, непонятно зачем, пытаетесь запустить еще один сервер. Ошибку ловит сервер, т.к. пытается писать в разорванное подключение. Поймал, обработал (залогировал например) и всё.

Comment: нужна правильная секция try-catch внутри метода connect. В Вашем коде в случае ошибки выходит совсем за пределы метода.

Comment: @KoVadim согласен но что в ней написать ? Как видите пока я в catch перезапускаю метод new Server_v0(); но это не совсем верное решение.

Comment: @KoVadim Немного перефразирую как правильно перезапустить сервер ?

Comment: я бы внутренности `while(true)` завернул бы. И перезапускать сервер не нужно. Это плохой сервер, если его нужно перезапускать, если клиенту поплохело.

Comment: @KoVadim Я не знаю на сколько это плохой сервер, но сейчас всё стало работать ошибка не появляется причём она была на двух разных версиях этого сервера подключение у них одинаковое только функционал разный. может есть предположение в чём может быть дело ?

Comment: просто клиент начал отключаться "удачно". И всех делов.

Comment: @KoVadim поспешил с вопросом она возникает кода передается множество файлов

Comment: У вас сервер однозадачный (т.е. в каждый момент времени к нему может быть подключено не более одного клиента). Сделайте сервер многозадачным (обрабатывайте клиентов в отдельных потоках или через асинхронное api), и ошибки подключения/отключения перестанут всё блокировать.

Comment: Чтобы не было ошибки Address already in use: JVM_Bind - закройте старый серверный сокет, там есть метод close(). Но еще раз повторюсь - это кривое решение, это всё равно что менять автомобиль после того как у него кончился бензин.

Comment: @Russtam можно по точнее в каком месте программы его закрыть ?

Comment: @VargSieg перед new Server_v0(); вызвать socket.close()  и в самом конце программы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас в коде много проблемок.

1. Если вы хотите работать с несколькими клиентами, то поступить нужно так:

   Создаем экземпляр сервера, создаем новый поток, в котором делаем `server.accept()` и складываем соединения в коллекцию/массив (можно запускать на каждый клиент поток), и в отдельном потоке работаем с соединенными клиентами

   Если вам нужно соединение с одним клиентом, то так:

   Сначала `server.accept()`, после этого запускаем цикл, в котором читаем файлы за итерацию, когда они попадают на вход. После этого не забываем закрыть сокеты
2. Нельзя оставлять просто так предыдущий сервер, нужно что-то сделать с открытыми соединениями при создании нового его экземпляра (правда я не понял, зачем)
3. Код оформлен как минимум странно